# List instances of Azure App Service with Powershell RM

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, octopus-deploy

My aim is to find all the instance Ids of a particular App Service in Azure so I can write a warm-up routine and test it against all running instances (ARRAfinity).

I can do the following with ASM Powershell but I need it in ARM (RM) as Octopus is configured for it.

```
(Get-AzureWebsite -Name "site-name" -Slot "Production").Instances
```

I have found the documentation around RM sparing, and the following hasn't led me to anything helpful:

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name "site-name"
```

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: How did you use the instance ids for your warm-up routine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/instances -Name $WebAppName -ApiVersion 2016-03-01
```

See also [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/bf195e051935a6db3db196c63d9e8a124fc12aa9/PowerShell/HelperFunctions.ps1#L117-L123) for a helper function that also works on slots.

Comment: Thanks David - just what I was looking for

Comment: Update as of September 2019:  you can use Az module and command Get-AzResource with same parameters to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use:

```
Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $WebAppName
```

Resource cmdlets should run faster than Get-AzResource (Get-AzureRmResource), specially with heavy scripts.

Comment: yeah but this doesn't list the separate instances